# How to get Logic Controller Name in JavaScript for a JMeter BSF Sampler test

Tags: javascript, jmeter

Is there a way to access a logic controller's name property within a BSF Script using JavaScript?

There is a simple controller whose name I want to access within a script farther down (similar to `getSampleLabel()`);

I am writing a series of tests which are all very similar, and I'm using the simple controller to name what each test is.  Ideally, when I look in a "view results tree" the results are displayed as the simple controller's name, even though under the hood it's all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add some param or function to the sample name, so during the test you will have 2 or more labels from the same. If you use a csv, maybe it contains a param that helps or add one.

```
name_sampler_${var_to_have_different_labels}
```